# Is $\mathbb R$ with usual euclidean topology, homeomorphic with some topological field of positive characteristic?

Tags: general-topology, topological-rings

Does there exists a topological field of positive characteristic which is homeomorphic with $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology ?

By homeomorphism here, I mean just topological homeomorphism, not necessarily preserving any algebraic structure.

Comment: I believe that locally compact topological fields are the same thing as local fields, and there are only two that are connected (R and C), so the answer is no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the map $\psi:x\mapsto x+1$ on a topological field $K$.
It's a homeomorphism from $K$ to itself, and it has no fixed points.
If $K$ has characteristic $p$ then $\psi$'s $p$-th power is the identity.

But on $\Bbb R$ every homeomorphism $\psi:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ without fixed points
is strictly increasing and either $\psi(x)-x$ is always positive
or $\psi(x)-x$ is always negative. So either $0<\psi(0)<\psi^2(0)<\psi^3(0)<
\cdots$ or $0>\psi(0)>\psi^2(0)>\psi^3(0)>
\cdots$. Either way, $\psi^p$ cannot be the identity.

Comment: "strictly increasing or strictly decreasing", you probably mean.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg No, no, no. I mean what I say!

Comment: Ah, I see now, sorry.

Comment: so basically, we can say that a topological group which is not torsion free, is not homeomorphic to real line with usual topology ... the same argument as that of yours go through (with $1$ replaced by a torsion element which is not the identity of the group ... )

Comment: @user521337 Indeed.